# Python Plotly static image export (Orca) getting html error 404

Tags: python, html, http-status-code-404, plotly, orca

I am running the Plotly offline static image export example as in https://plot.ly/python/static-image-export/. Unfortunately I get the following error running the below line I cant decipher. Every other step is successful, including plot render. Is it reaching out to an external address?

```
pio.write_image(fig, format='png',file='images/fig1.png')
```

Error:

```
ValueError: 
The image request was rejected by the orca conversion utility
with the following error:
 404: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 
4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Not Found</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii">
</HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Not Found</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
```

Comment: `pio.write_image(go.Figure(data=[{'y': [1, 3, 2]}]), 'simple_fig.png')` Can you check with a different/simpler figure?

Comment: Same error, and not a fantastic error message.

Comment: The examples should work in sessions launched from [here](https://github.com/fomightez/orca-plotly-binderized). Maybe by comparing where it goes wrong you can track down your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set your NO_PROXY environment variable to localhost maty.